# Stream Web Audio with WebRTC without asking for microphone

Tags: webrtc, audio-streaming, web-audio-api

I want to stream audio from a web page to a local server, using WebRTC. That server will process that audio and will output it immediately to the user. I need real time.

My code is actually working. However I am asking the user for the microphone with getUserMedia, and I don't need that microphone. This is quite annoying. What can I do in order to stream the audio without having to ask the user for the microphone?

Thank you.

Here is a minimal working example (it is highly inspired by https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc/blob/main/examples/server/client.js). Only the last part with comments is interesting :

```
let webSocket = new WebSocket('wss://0.0.0.0:8080/ws');
const config = { sdpSemantics: 'unified-plan' }

const pc = new RTCPeerConnection(config);

webSocket.onmessage = (message) => {
    const data = JSON.parse(message.data); 
    switch(data.type) {
        case "answer":
            pc.setRemoteDescription(data.answer)
            break;
        default: 
            break; 
    }
};

function negotiate() {
    return pc.createOffer()
    .then(function(offer) {
        return pc.setLocalDescription(offer);
    })
    .then(function() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve) {
            if (pc.iceGatheringState === 'complete') {
                resolve();
            } else {
                function checkState() {
                    if (pc.iceGatheringState === 'complete') {
                        pc.removeEventListener('icegatheringstatechange', checkState);
                        resolve();
                    }
                }
                pc.addEventListener('icegatheringstatechange', checkState);
            }
        });
    })
    .then(function() {
        const offer = pc.localDescription;
        webSocket.send(
            JSON.stringify({
                type: "offer",
                offer: {
                    sdp: offer.sdp,
                    type: offer.type
                }
            })
        );
    })
}

// Preparing the oscillator
const audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
const oscillator = audioCtx.createOscillator();
const serverDestination = audioCtx.createMediaStreamDestination();
oscillator.connect(serverDestination);

// Asking for useless microphone
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true})
.then(() => {
    return negotiate();
});

// Actual streaming
const stream = new MediaStream();
serverDestination.stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
    pc.addTrack(track, stream);
})

// User pushes button to start the oscillator
function play() {
    oscillator.start();
};
```

Comment: It might be a problem with aiortc and mDNS: https://github.com/feross/simple-peer/issues/502#issuecomment-511221792
aiortc did not support mDNS until a couple of days ago, after I downloaded it for the first time. However I've updated it and it still does not work. Maybe it is still buggy. I'll consider to try with an other backend eventually.

Comment: According to aiortc developer, there is currently a bug in Firefox: https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc/issues/481

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of this:

```
// Asking for useless microphone
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true})
.then(() => {
    return negotiate();
});
```

As you say, it's useless and not necessary.  If you don't call `getUserMedia()`, the user won't be prompted to share their microphone.  You can make WebRTC connections without this.

I suspect the problem you're running into is that your audio context is paused.  If you call `audioCtx.resume()` when a user clicks a button, you'll be up and running.  This is due to autoplay policy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I forgot to take account of the autoplay policy in my "minimal example". In my real code, the user has to push a button. I edited my example. It still does not work if I replace the whole "getUserMedia" thing by a simple "negotiate" and I add audioCtx.resume().

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need user media, don't ask for it with getUserMedia in your code.